# How do I call an itemStack from another Class?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm making a Custom Horse plugin and this is the first real plugin that I'm making so please excuse my messy code.

In one class (HorseSaddles) I have created 4 different saddles:

```
package io.github.bxnie.Items;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;

import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;

public class HorseSaddles implements Listener {
    public void DonkeyHorse() {
        ItemStack dhorse = new ItemStack(Material.SADDLE);
        ItemMeta dhorsemeta = dhorse.getItemMeta();

        dhorsemeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Donkey");
        ArrayList<String> dhorselore = new ArrayList<String>();
        dhorselore.add(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "1/4");
        dhorselore.add(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "Right click to spawn your Donkey!");
        dhorsemeta.setLore(dhorselore);
        dhorse.setItemMeta(dhorsemeta);
    }

    public void BrownHorse() {
        ItemStack brhorse = new ItemStack(Material.SADDLE);
        ItemMeta brhorsemeta = brhorse.getItemMeta();

        brhorsemeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Brown Horse");
        ArrayList<String> brhorselore = new ArrayList<String>();
        brhorselore.add(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "2/4");
        brhorselore.add(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "Right click to spawn your Horse!");
        brhorsemeta.setLore(brhorselore);
        brhorse.setItemMeta(brhorsemeta);
    }

    public void BlackHorse() {
        ItemStack blhorse = new ItemStack(Material.SADDLE);
        ItemMeta blhorsemeta = blhorse.getItemMeta();

        blhorsemeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.BLACK + "Black" + ChatColor.RED + "Horse");
        ArrayList<String> blhorselore = new ArrayList<String>();
        blhorselore.add(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "3/4");
        blhorselore.add(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "Right click to spawn your Horse!");
        blhorsemeta.setLore(blhorselore);
        blhorse.setItemMeta(blhorsemeta);
    }

    public void WhiteHorse() {
        ItemStack whorse = new ItemStack(Material.SADDLE);
        ItemMeta whorsemeta = whorse.getItemMeta();

        whorsemeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.WHITE + "White" + ChatColor.RED + "Horse");
        ArrayList<String> whorselore = new ArrayList<String>();
        whorselore.add(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "4/4");
        whorselore.add(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "Right click to spawn your Horse!");
        whorsemeta.setLore(whorselore);
        whorse.setItemMeta(whorsemeta);
    }
}
```

And in another class (SaddleCommands) I am attempting to create a command which will give the user that an that item if they have the correct permissions

```
package io.github.bxnie.commands;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

import net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.CommandExecute;

public class SaddleCommands extends CommandExecute implements Listener, CommandExecutor{

    public String cmd1 = "fhdonkey";

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] arg3) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("Only players may execute this command!");
            return true;
        }

        Player p = (Player) sender;
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(cmd1)) {
            if (p.hasPermission("fh.donkey")) {
                p.sendMessage("You Have Purchased a Donkey");
                p.getInventory().addItem(...);
                return true;
            } else {
                p.sendMessage("§cInsufficient Permission!");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

where it says `p.getInventory().addItem(...);` i put in the 3dots as a placeholder as I don't know how to retrieve an item from another class.

Comment: Check the type that the method accepts. What is addItem looking for in it's parameter?

Comment: the `addItem()` is supposed to be adding the item from `public void DonkeyHorse()` which is in the HorseSaddles class file, although I'm not sure how to link them so to speak

Comment: Check the type of the parameter? When you have a method, you've got a parameter, like this: `public void thisMethod(int parameter)`. What is the type of the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the forum :)

You created an Class HorseSaddles. In there you got 3 functions which create an ItemStack, without doing anything with the object. Simply just return the ItemStack object.

i created an minimalistic solution:

```
public class Horse {
// we create an function which returns an ItemStack
    public ItemStack getBrownHorseItemStack() {
        // Create the ItemStack Object
        ItemStack horseItem = new Itemstack(Material.SADDLE);
        // return our ItemStack Object
        return horseItem;
    }
}

class Saddle {

    private Horse horse = new Horse();

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        // an CommandSender object is NOT always an Player Object. Normally we would check if sender is a Player Object
        // We cast the CommandSender to an player
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        // check the command received
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("fhdonkey")) {
            // horse.getBrownHorseItemStack() will return an ItemStack Object
            player.getInventory().addItem(horse.getBrownHorseItemStack());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

for more informations: [Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Comment: @Squiddie yes you are completly right. Gonna improve my Answer when i am @ home :)